# nexus 5x stuck on Google screen after replacing one of the system shared libraries

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-rom

My nexus 5x works fine until I changed some share library in system partition:

```
adb push out/target/product/bullhead/system/lib/somename.so /system/lib/somename.so
adb reboot
```

then my nexus 5x is stuck on Google screen on boot. But when I cleared data, my nexus 5x works fine again:

```
fastboot -w && fastboot reboot
```

I also find that system.img can't be flashed alone, I must wipe data using **fastboot -w** when I flash the system.img, or it will stuck on Google screen on boot. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Just for your knowledge, the `nexus` tag relates to Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager, not to the phone. I removed it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot, and finally it worked, I'm not sure which one of these solved my problem, but I believe it has something to do with:

```
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
```

Hope it will work for you.